# How to use a function from a header file without including the header in C?

Tags: c, header-files

Suppose I have a header file `abc.h` which defines a function `foo()`. How can I use the function `foo()` in the header file `abc.h` without using `#include<abc.h>` in my program?

I could come up with the following solutions

- Copy the function from the header file into the program manually. But this would fail for most of the cases where the function definition has been pre-compiled into object files. Because in that case copy pasting function prototype won't do any good because unresolved references to the function couldn't be resolved.
- Don't do anything in case of standard libraries as IDE can take care of that. But this is obviously undefined behaviour and would depend on IDE. Also for non-standard libraries it would surely fail.

So how can I use a function in a header file(not necessarily from the standard library) without including the header file?

This was an interview question so it is essentially a trick question. Not real use.

Comment: "this would fail for most of the cases where the header has been pre-compiled into object files" - I'm not sure what that means.  A function declaration via a `#include` is the same as a function declaration in your source file itself.

Comment: Why specifically do you want to use a function from a header file without actually including it?

Comment: You can't. If you could, then there is no real need to include any header files. The only way is copy & paste, but then, you might as well use the `#include`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This was an interview question so the only restriction was not to use `#include` at the top. I know that it is essentially the same but doing pre-processing had been taken out so I came up with the next solution - manual copy and paste. Not the best but that's what I could think of.

Comment: @DennisMeng Interview question so it is essentailly a trick question. I don't want to do that in real code.

Comment: @inixsoftware Interview question so there has to be some kind of workaround. A hack. Not intended for real use. Otherwise why would it have been asked?

Comment: The header should not 'define' the function; it should only declare it (unless, perhaps, it is an inline function).  Since headers are intended to declare the functions you need, why are you unwilling or unable to include the relevant header in your code?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know that it isn't the best way to do things but as I said this was how it was asked in the interview.

Comment: In an interview, or anywhere else, the first clarification question should be: "Did you mean 'defined' or 'declared' in the header?"  In an interview, it is good to ask clarification questions — the main question is often asked ambiguously or giving incomplete information, precisely to see what you do with the ambiguity or incomplete information.  What you do after that depends on the answer to 'defined' vs 'declared', but the answers are different depending on that distinction.  Asking for clarification takes guts, but are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the key word here is "defined" in the header file, not just declared. The header would have to be compiled to an object. To use it, you'd "declare" the function in your source and link with the object file.

That said, I hate interview questions like this since you're never really sure if that's what they are looking for because no one in their right mind would do this in practice.

Answer (score 0):

> But this would fail for most of the cases where the header has been pre-compiled into object files

This sentence makes no sense. A header can be *used* to compile an object file, but they never get compiled *into* object files; they are always used externally.

Comment: What I meant was the function definitions are compiled into object files while the function prototypes are in the header files. If I am not allowed to use the header in my source code then linking to the object file would not be possible. Hence copy pasting prototype from the header won't do any good. I'll edit the question.

Comment: You don't need the header to link to the object file. Linking is a completely independent operation from compiling.

Comment: This I tend to forget. A disadvantage of using an IDE and developing on Windows. Thanks.